# ASP.NET MVC 3 controller .Json method serialization doesn't look at DataMember Name attribure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, serialization, controller

In my class i've got:

```
[DataMember(Name = "jsonMemberName", EmitDefaultValue = false, 
    IsRequired = false)]
public List<string> Member { get; set; }
```

After passing the object through controller's Json(obj) that retruns System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult: i've got serialized json: {Member:...} but not {jsonMemberName:...}, so it doesn't look at DataMember(Name = "jsonMemberName").

If I use serialization from System.Runtime.Serialization.Json everithing's works fine as expected.

What can be wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC: Controlling serialization of property names with JsonResult](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302946/asp-net-mvc-controlling-serialization-of-property-names-with-jsonresult)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [JsonResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult.aspx) action which you are returning from the controller action (using `return Json(...)`) internally relies on the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class. This class doesn't take into account any `DataMember` attributes on your model.

You could write a custom ActionResult which uses the serializer in the `System.Runtime.Serialization.Json` namespace.

For example:

```
public class MyJsonResult : JsonResult
{
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ContentType))
        {
            response.ContentType = ContentType;
        }
        else
        {
            response.ContentType = "application/json";
        }
        if (ContentEncoding != null)
        {
            response.ContentEncoding = this.ContentEncoding;
        }
        if (Data != null)
        {
            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(Data.GetType());
            serializer.WriteObject(response.OutputStream, Data);
        }
    }
}
```

and then in your controller action:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    var model = ...
    return new MyJsonResult { Data = model };
}
```

Comment: So is there a solution? Without renaming members in class, becouse its ugly.

Comment: @WHITECOLOR, sure, write a custom `ActionResult`.

Comment: It would be nice to vote for a change request or similar in MVC. What would be the drawback if the default JSONResult used the DataContractJsonSerializer. Would it break something?

Answer (score 2):

`System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult` usea the old `JavaScriptSerializer` class, which doesn't know anything about the DataAnnotiations assembly. You need to use the [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) instead.

You can use this instead on JsonResult if you so desire:

```
public class DataContractJsonResult : JsonResult
{
    public DataContractJsonResult(object data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }

    public DataContractJsonResult()
    {
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }
        if (JsonRequestBehavior == JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet &&
            String.Equals(context.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod, "GET", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet.");
        }

        HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ContentType))
        {
            response.ContentType = ContentType;
        }
        else
        {
            response.ContentType = "application/json";
        }
        if (ContentEncoding != null)
        {
            response.ContentEncoding = ContentEncoding;
        }
        if (Data != null)
        {
            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(Data.GetType());
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            serializer.WriteObject(ms, Data);
            string json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            response.Write(json);
        }
    }
}
```

(I referenced the ASP.NET MVC source code to create this. Not sure if I have to credit it in some way. Well, more than this aside already is, that is. :))

You can also add this to a base class from which your controllers inherit:

```
protected JsonResult DataContractJson(object data)
{
    return new DataContractJsonResult(data);
}
```