# DataMember attribute not affects on json result

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-mvc

I have this model with System.Runtime.Serialization attributes:

```
[DataContract]
public class DataTableItemModel
{
    [DataMember(Name = "targets")]
    public int[] Targets { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "visible")]
    public bool Visible { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "searchable")]
    public bool Searchable { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string Field { get; set; }
}
```

And after that in Razor Model.DataTablesDescription (this is `List<DataTableItemModel>`):
    `@Html.Raw(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.DataTablesDescription))`
or
`@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.DataTablesDescription))`

Output HTML looks as:
`[{"Targets":[0],"Visible":false,"Searchable":false,"Field":"Id"}, ...]`

but I expected:
`[{"targets":[0],"visible":false,"searchable":false,"name":"Id"},`
i.e. subject to DataMember attributes.

What's wrong?

Comment: Might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020889/asp-net-mvc-3-controller-json-method-serialization-doesnt-look-at-datamember-n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `JavaScriptSerializer` would not take your `[DataMember]`/`[DataContract]` into account.

Try to use the `DataContractJsonSerializer`:

For example:

```
@{
var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(DataTableItemModel));
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

serializer.WriteObject(memoryStream, Model.DataTablesDescription);

@Html.Raw(new StreamReader(memoryStream).ReadToEnd())
}
```

Alternatively, use [Json.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) instead:

```
@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.DataTablesDescription));
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx)

Comment: Json.NET perfectly works with DataMember attributes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
[DataContract]
public class DataTableItemModel
{
    [DataMember]
    [DisplayName("targets")]
    public int[] Targets { get; set; }
}
```